# One of my IC1004-WH Legrand ON-Q Inquire 1000 intercoms isn't working, is it possible a POE injector would help?

Tags: low-voltage

One of my IC1004-WH Legrand ON-Q Inquire 1000 intercoms isn't working, is it possible a POE injector would help? It's a pretty long run, although other longer ones are working. It has worked somewhat in the past but gave a bad hum. Now it doesn't work at all. I have two different ones I've tried, with the same result. Circuit checker says I've got continuity all the way through but I know it might not be enough to carry a power signal.

Comment: While these units use Cat 5e cable, it is not at all clear that they use (or could even tolerate!) POE. What "Circuit checker" did you use? I would test with something that can do an end-to-end test of all 8 wires to make sure nothing is broken or miswired. Probably best to reterminate both ends (T568A though T568B is OK as long as both ends are the same).

Comment: What does the product documentation say about that? What does it say about maximum cable runs? You could certainly give it a try, but you may end up frying your equipment, so I'd suggest you contact the mfgr if you can't find the answer it the docs - they'll know for certain.